# Accessing JWT token in ios sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am currently using the ios sdk, does anyone know how to get the jwt token?

Can an unauthenticated user get a jwt token?

Comment: hey, having the same issue. Did u solve the problem?

Comment: @Dirder I should have wrote the solution, I can't remember exactly; Once I logged in with Cognito, it was accessible within the API

Comment: cool, don't you have any sample code with that on swift for objc? Would be really appreciated..